# Retrieve a selected option value in a component for React-bootstrap Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

It is a Form that can retrieve value selected from a option.

```
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function FormTestPage() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("L1");
  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <Form.Group className="InputField">
          <Form.Label>Level</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            as="select"
            value={selected}
            onChange={(event) => setSelected(event.target.value)}
          >
            <option value="L1">L1</option>
            <option value="L2">L2</option>
            <option value="L3">L3</option>
          </Form.Control>
        </Form.Group> 
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Selected
        </Button>
      </Form>
  );
}
```

I am trying to split code to a component for re-using it, but the value selected cannot retrieve when submit button is clicked in FormTestPage:

`FormTestPage`

```
import SelectField from "../components/SelectField";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";

export default function FormTestPage() {
  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <SelectField onSubmit={onSubmit}/>
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Selected
        </Button>
      </Form>
  );
}
```

`SelectField`

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";

function SelectField(onSubmit) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("L1");
  return (
    <Form.Group className="InputField">
      <Form.Label>Level</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control
        as="select"
        value={selected}
        onSubmit={(event) => {
          setSelected(event.target.value);
        }}
      >
        <option value="L1">L1</option>
        <option value="L2">L2</option>
        <option value="L3">L3</option>
      </Form.Control>
    </Form.Group>
  );
}

export default SelectField;
```

I tried also with useState variables passing as props to SelectField without success. Thanks

Comment: First, pass the onSubmit prop in the SelectField Component Form Tag.

Comment: It's onChange instead of onSubmit in <Form.Control>

Answer (score 0):

There was 2 issues in above code:

1. `FormTestPage` component has useState hook and will pass its variable to `SelectField`. It also will receive **props.selected** option.  Noted that `L1` is passed as default value in useState hook
2. `SelectField` component has to receive useState variable from `FormTestPage` and it **onChange event** for set the option selected by user.

`FormTestPage`

```
import SelectField from "../components/SelectField";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function FormTestPage() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("L1");

  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(selected);
  };

  return (
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <SelectField selected=Selected setselected=setSelected/>
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Selected
        </Button>
      </Form>
  );
}
```

`SelectField`

```
export default function SelectField({ selected, setSelected }) {
 return (
   <Form.Group className="InputField">
     <Form.Label>Level</Form.Label>
     <Form.Control
       as="select"
       value={selected}
       onChange={(event) => {
         setSelected(event.target.value);
       }}
     >
       <option value="L1">L1</option>
       <option value="L2">L2</option>
       <option value="L3">L3</option>
     </Form.Control>
   </Form.Group>
 );
 }
```